# How do you install/Use Treed Control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, less, browserify, webpack

I've used some JS and Jquery controls before that Im totally lost in this.

I really like this control: https://github.com/jaredly/treed but I cant find a way of making it work. Not even running the sample within the demo. I installed node.JS on my machine but I am not too sure how I can install the rest:

-- [browserify](http://browserify.org) `npm install -g browserify watchify`

-- [less](http://lesscss.org) `npm install -g less`

+- [webpack](http://webpack.github.io) `npm install -g webpack`

My machine is a Windows machine.

Comment: I'm running into this is exact same issue.  Attempting to figure out as well.  I downloaded the master and I have all the files available, just having trouble figuruing out what to reference/use.